# Why Rails 5 is not saving nested attributes because parent model is not saving first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am using Rails 5 and everything at its newest stable versions. So I get the following :

> You have your association set to required but it's missing.
>   Associations are set to required by default in rails 5 so if you want
>   to keep one empty you need to set optional:true on your association in
>   mode

This is great and I understand what is going on however for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the parent model to save first so the user_id is translated the nested models record. I see the same answer above everywhere however no one explains a work around other than turning the default in the initializer from true to false. THIS DOES NOT SOLVE THE PROBLEM, because the record sure does save but it does not include the user_id.

Below is what I have for my code base, I would ask rather than responding with the above quote, could someone enlighten me on HOW to get the USER_ID field into the nested attributes while saving. I refuse to disable validation and manually handle the insertion, as this is not the ruby way and breaks from standards!
Thanks in advance for anyone who can answer this question directly and without vague explanations that digress from the ruby way of things!

```
###Models
#Users
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end

#Profiles
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :profile
end

###Controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_profile
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user.build_profile
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :user_type_id, profile_attributes: [:user_id, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :cell_number, :email])
    end
end

##View
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
        <!--<li><%= debug f %></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <% if params[:trainer] == "true" %>
      <%= f.label :user_type_id %>
      <%= f.text_field :user_type_id, :readonly => true, :value => '2' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.label :user_type_id %>
      <%= f.text_field :user_type_id, :readonly => true, :value => '1'  %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
    <h2>Account Profile</h2>
    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
      <%#= profile.inspect %>
        <div>
          <%= profile.label :first_name %>
          <%= profile.text_field :first_name %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= profile.label :middle_name %>
          <%= profile.text_field :middle_name %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= profile.label :last_name %>
          <%= profile.text_field :last_name %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= profile.label :email %>
          <%= profile.text_field :email %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= profile.label :phone_number %>
          <%= profile.telephone_field :phone_number %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= profile.label :cell_phone %>
          <%= profile.telephone_field :cell_number %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
    <%= debug params %>
    <%= debug user %>
    <%= debug user.profile %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**
For starters I have figured out that you need to include **autosave: true** to the relationship like so

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Then the parent record gets saved before the child. Now comes another gotcha that I am just not sure about and is odd when the form is submitted you will notice in the console output I pasted below that the **INSERT INTO `profiles`** statement includes the **user_id** column and the value of **1**. It passees validation and looks like it runs properly from the output, however the **user_id** column in the **profiles** table is still null. I am going to keep digging, hopefuly one of my fellow rubyiests out there will see this and have some ideas on how to finish fixing this. I love Rails 5 improvements so far but it wouldn't be ROR without small interesting gotchas! Thanks again in advance!

```
Started POST "/users" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-12 22:28:14 -0400
Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YA7kQnScvlIBy5OiT+BmOQ2bR7J00ANXId38FqNwX37Cejd+6faUyD3rMF4y0qJNKBUYGaxrRZqcLrXonL6ymA==", "user"=>{"username"=>"john", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_type_id"=>"1", "profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"john", "middle_name"=>"r", "last_name"=>"tung", "email"=>"thegugaru@gmail.com", "phone_number"=>"8033207677", "cell_number"=>"8033207677"}}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `user_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('john', '0000', 1, '2017-03-13 02:28:14', '2017-03-13 02:28:14')
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `profiles` (`user_id`, `email`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `cell_number`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 'thegu@gmail.com', 'john', 'r', 'tung', '8033207677', '8033207677', '2017-03-13 02:28:14', '2017-03-13 02:28:14')
   (10.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://192.168.0.51:3000/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 11.5ms)
```

Comment: the `autosave` option is explained greatly in detail in the Rails official docs.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I am answering my own question because I know many people are struggling with this and I actually have the answer and not a vague response to the documentation.

First we will just be using a one to one relationship for this example. When you create your relationships you need to make sure that the parent model has the following

1. inverse_of:
2. autosave: true
3. accepts_nested_attributes_for :model, allow_destroy:true

Here is the Users model then I will explain,

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end
```

in Rails 5 you need inverse_of: because this tells Rails that there is a relationship through foreign key and that it needs to be set on the nested model when saving your form data.

Now if you were to leave **autosave: true** off from the relationship line you are left with the **user_id** not saving to the profiles table and just the other columns, unless you have validations off and then it won't error out it will just save it without the **user_id**.

What is going on here is **autosave: true** is making sure that the user record is saved first so that it has the **user_id** to store in the nested attributes for the **profile** model.

That is it in a nutshell why the **user_id** was not traversing to the child and it was rolling back rather than committing.

Also one last gotcha is there are some posts out there telling you in your controller for the edit route you should add **@user.build_profile** like I have in my post. DO NOT DO IT THEY ARE DEAD WRONG, after assessing the console output it results in

```
Started GET "/users/1/edit" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-12 22:38:17 -0400
Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `profiles` SET `user_id` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2017-03-13 02:38:17' WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 1
   (59.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (44.8ms)
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (50.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 98.6ms | ActiveRecord: 61.1ms)
```

If you look it is rebuilding the profile from scratch and resetting the user_id to null for the record that matches the current user you are editing.

So be very careful of this as I have seen tons of posts making this suggestion and it cost me DAYS of research to find a solution!

Comment: The reason why you don't need the `@user.build_profile` in your edit action is because you are already saving a `profile` record associated to your user.   If a user without a `profile` record goes to the edit user page, they'll never see the form for the profile.  So just check if profile exists or not before calling `@user.build_profile`.

Comment: As I said in my response, I realize that and I was explaining it here because it seems that people around the net like to advise incorrectly on this and being a seasoned professional I have a big problem with misinformation.

Comment: But you haven't explained why you don't need that at all.  You just said that it's wrong to do that.  Like I said, it's on a case to case basis.  If it doesn't work on your app, it doesn't mean it will not work on others.

Comment: From the documentation it should never be in the edit  unless you encapsulate it in a check to see if the record exists. However if your app is setup right that is not even needed. If you read my post fully you will notice that i mention this issue but that is not what the focus of my post is. Your comments feel like you are splitting hairs and not reading the post for its intended purpose, which is getting nested models to save properly with the parent without removing validation. Sounds like you just wanted to criticize someone.

Comment: I was having the same issue, but only adding the inverse_of attribute solved my problem (without declaring autosave).

Comment: Am facing same issue, however this solution is not working for me, and I am trying to save parent object in a rake tasks, so no controller stuff, all model level stuff

Comment: @Amol Pujari if you are speaking of dealing with this in direct relation to using it in an actual rake command then I would advise you to start another post. As this post does not include rake at all. If you could start a post explain in detail what your doing and what is going wrong and then edit your comment to include the link that would be great and I would be glad to take a look at your issue.